# Gantt package and milestones

Tags: pgfgantt

Does anybody know how can I put several milestones in the same line? 
The only way I figured out is like in the picture (different lines) and so I did in the code below but it would be better to have all the milestones as one single line.

The code has been modified as I put more commands to be compiled correctly.
For those who try you will need the file `gantt.sty` from http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=05Misc:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{gantt}
  \begin{document}
   \begin{flushleft}
   \scalebox{0.7}{
    \begin{gantt}{10}{18}
    \begin{ganttitle}
     \titleelement{\textbf{2016}}{18}
     \end{ganttitle}
    \begin{ganttitle} 
       \titleelement{\textbf{April}}{2}
     \titleelement{\textbf{May}}{2}
  \titleelement{\textbf{June}}{2}
  \titleelement{\textbf{July}}{2}
  \titleelement{\textbf{August}}{2}
  \titleelement{\textbf{September}}{2}
   \titleelement{\textbf{October}}{2}
  \titleelement{\textbf{November}}{2}
   \titleelement{\textbf{December}}{2}
\end{ganttitle}
  \begin{ganttitle}

   \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-30}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-31}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-30}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-31}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-31}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-30}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-31}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-30}{1}
  \titleelement{01-15}{1}
  \titleelement{16-31}{1}
  \end{ganttitle}
 \ganttgroup{\textsc{\textbullet\ Internal Organization}}{0}{8}
\ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=blue]{\textsf{- Responsible}}{2}{1}
\ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=blue]{\textsf{- Work spaces}}{2}{1}
\ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=red]{- \textbf{Inventory}}{2}{6}
\ganttmilestone[color=red]{\sffamily{\textit{\textcolor{red}{Checkpoint}}}}{4} 
\ganttmilestone[color=red]{\sffamily{\textit{\textcolor{red}{Checkpoint}}}}{5} 
\ganttgroup{\textsc{\textbullet\ Kick-Off}}{10}{6}
 \end{gantt}
  }
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Thank to all!

Comment: Can you make a complete, compilable example? Where does the `ganttitle` environment and `\titlelement` macro come from, for example? Also, the main environment defined by `pgfgantt` is called `ganttchart`, not just `gantt`.

Comment: I used the package gantt available with an auxiliar file called gantt.sty

Comment: And where did you find `gantt.sty`? It's not on CTAN, so not in TeX Live or MikTeX.

Comment: Here: http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=Projects:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots

Comment: Note that the link has changed to http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=05Misc:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package stores the row number in a counter called `ganttnum`. You can manually adjust this counter with `\addtocounter{ganttnum}{n}`to set the row where you want the next plot element (e.g., milestone) to appear. Positive numbers are up, negative numbers are down. If you want multiple elements on one line then you should leave the description blank for all but the first element, otherwise Tikz will draw them slightly shifted at the same position.

Example:

```
\ganttgroup{\textsc{\textbullet\ Internal Organization}}{0}{8}
\ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=blue]{\textsf{- Responsible}}{2}{1}
\ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=blue]{\textsf{- Work spaces}}{2}{1}
\ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=red]{- \textbf{Inventory}}{2}{6}
\ganttmilestone[color=red]{\sffamily{\textit{\textcolor{red}{Checkpoint}}}}{4} 
\addtocounter{ganttnum}{1}
\ganttmilestone[color=red]{\sffamily{\textit{\textcolor{red}{}}}}{5}
\ganttgroup{\textsc{\textbullet\ Kick-Off}}{10}{3}
\addtocounter{ganttnum}{2}
\ganttmilestone[color=red]{\sffamily{\textit{\textcolor{red}{}}}}{13}
\addtocounter{ganttnum}{-1}
\ganttgroup{\textsc{\textbullet\ Prototype}}{13}{2}
\addtocounter{ganttnum}{3}
\ganttmilestone[color=red]{\sffamily{\textit{\textcolor{red}{}}}}{15}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly. Cheers!!!